# How to run a python background process periodically

Tags: python, unix, cron

I have a fairly light script that I want to run periodically in the background every 5 hours or so. The script runs through a few different websites, scans them for new material, and either grabs .mp3 files from them or likes songs on youtube based on their content. There are a few things I want to achieve with this program that I am unsure of how to attain:

- Have the program run every 5 hours -- I'm not to familiar with system-level timing operations.
- Have the program efficiently run in the background -- I want these 'updates' to occur without the user knowing.
- Have the program activate on startup -- I know how I would set this up as a user, but I'm not sure how to add such a configuration to the python file, if that's even possible. Keep in mind that this is going to be a simple .py script -- I'm not compiling it into an executable.

The program is designed mainly with OSX and other Unix based systems in mind. Any advice on achieving some of these goals?

Comment: This sounds like a cron http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: Definately cron, look maybe at [this examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/crontab-tutorial/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your script doesn't need to be constantly in execution, and it sounds like it doesn't, I'd suggest you set up a cron job.

On a typical Linux box, you can edit your `crontab file` via:

```
$ crontab -e
```

This will open your crontab in your standard editor and install the crontab file for you after you're done (i.e. you save it)

A typical crontab command looks like:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 15  0   *   *   *    /bin/bash /home/yourself/bin/dump_my_tables.sh
```

this line will execute `dump_my_tables.sh` every day at 00:15. Your script will need a like like the following:

```
0  */5  *  *  *   /usr/bin/python /home/yourself/bin/scrape_the_web.py
```

nb:

- Time is the machine's local time (!)
- Some `cron` versions don't accept `*/5` syntax, you have to manually specify the hours when you want the script to be scheduled, i.e. `0,5,10,15,20`
- You might want to redirect output, but it's out of this answers' scope

Answer (score 2):

> Have the program run every 5 hours -- I'm not to familiar with
>   system-level timing operations.

for nix cron is the default solution to accomplish this

> Have the program efficiently run in the background -- I want these
>   'updates' to occur without the user knowing.

Using cron the program will be run in the background on your server.  The user shouldn't be adversly affected by it.  If the user loads a page viewing mp3s you have scraped.  Then in the midst of your script running/saving data to the database the user hits refresh, the new mp3's might show up, i don't know if this is what you had in mind  by "without the user knowing"

> Have the program activate on startup -- I know how I would set this up
>   as a user, but I'm not sure how to add such a configuration to the
>   python file, if that's even possible. Keep in mind that this is going
>   to be a simple .py script -- I'm not compiling it into an executable.

I'm pretty sure cron entries will persist at reboot, (i'm not 100%), make sure that `cron` daemon is started on boot

Comment: Cron entries *do* persist at reboot and cron is also "auto-started". Our answers are complementary since I focused just on the cron part :) +1