# How to run a Python package as a scheduled daemon job?

Tags: python, linux, macos, cron, daemon

I have created a Python package and released it on PyPI, say `spamandeggs`. This package is cross-platform (Windows,GNU/Linux, MacOSX) aimed at updating the user with certain information periodically (say every 5 minutes). The package can be run from command-line through the command `spamtheeggs`.

Here are the issues I am facing:

***Question 01*: How to daemonize the script running through the `spamtheeggs` command?**

***Problem***: Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/4927751) answer, I tried using `schedule` in my script. This works fine for scheduling but the execution is not daemonized. The terminal is busy for the entirety of the process.
I would like to know a way to daemonise the Python package.

***Question 02*: How to add the command as a cron job for scheduled execution ?**

**Solution 01**: One way to do this would be to write an installation guide describing the process (editing crontab using `crontab -e`, etc.).
**Drawback**: Not appealing.

**Solution 02**: As the author of the package, I want to be able to add this command to the user's crontab (after getting user's confirmation, obviously).

Options:

1. Write a Python script to schedule another script (Is this even possible?)
2. Use a task scheduler which can also daemonize.

I would like to know which option is suitable(if any) and any tips on how can I go about working on them.

List of resources I have read so far:

- [How to run a python background process periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14614196/4927751)
- [Scheduling Python Script to run every hour accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately)
- [How to package a Python daemon with setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722455/how-to-package-a-python-daemon-with-setuptools)
- [Execute python Script on Crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab)
- [running a python script with cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460262/running-a-python-script-with-cron)
- [Creating a Cron Job - Linux / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339725/creating-a-cron-job-linux-python)
- [How to make Python script run as service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420092/how-to-make-python-script-run-as-service)

Note: I would appreciate if the solution is applicable over all the 3 platforms.
P.S: This is my first attempt at cron and daemon jobs.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww Thanks for notifying me about this. I considered posting this question here because it satisfied the last two points of the SO guidelines: `software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`. But if you do not think likewise, feel free to move it to a more suitable site.

Answer (score 1):

`python-deamon` package can help you, it works in 2 modes:

- using a runner (I think is just what you want): http://www.gavinj.net/2012/06/building-python-daemon-process.html
- or running using `daemon.DaemonContext` directly (a more traditional way)

`python-deamon` has no documentation, but I've found some code that may help you http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/10392/daemon.DaemonContext

Comment: This kind of links may become broken over the time, it would be better if, in addition, you could summarise them and improve your post with an example.